# Issue with installing yeoman

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I am trying to install yeoman with node 4.8.7.

```
npm install -g yo
```

This is the error I get :

> ```
> C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.8.7\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-doctor\lib\index.js:12
>       (async () => {
>              ^
>
>     SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
>         at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>         at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>         at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>         at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>         at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thomas\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.8.7\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-doctor\lib\cli.js:3:1)
>         at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>     npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18362
>     npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
> "--global" "yo"
>     npm ERR! node v4.8.7
>     npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
>     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
>     npm ERR! yo@3.1.1 postinstall: `yodoctor`
>     npm ERR! Exit status 1
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! Failed at the yo@3.1.1 postinstall script 'yodoctor'.
>     npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
>     npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>     npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>     npm ERR!     yodoctor
>     npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>     npm ERR!     npm bugs yo
>     npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
>     npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
>     npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>     npm ERR!     C:\Users\thomas\dev\workspace\aprhtechvalley\npm-debug.log
> ```

any idea how to solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please update your NodeJS to the latest version, which is 12: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

---

Or, if you need to install it via NVM: https://tecadmin.net/install-nodejs-with-nvm/

Comment: I need to use this version of nodejs in order to make an old project work.

Comment: Try to install lower versions of `yo`: `npm install -g yo@version numbering`. A complete list of deployed versions can be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/yo

Comment: Try each version until it works. Note that lower versions may have security vulnerabilities